# 'NullReferenceException was unhandled' in C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, unhandled

I am having a nullreferenceexception error in my code in this line:

```
public bool BoundingVolumeIsInView(BoundingSphere sphere)
    {
        **return (Frustum.Contains(sphere) != ContainmentType.Disjoint);**
    }
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Either `sphere`, or `Frustum` could be null.

Comment: I think `Frustrum` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`Frustum` is probably `null`. Use a debugger and check it. You could do something like this to prevent null pointer exceptions

```
if(Frustum != null)
    return (Frustum.Contains(sphere) != ContainmentType.Disjoint);
return false;
```